# Images sometimes wrong size only in Chrome mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

EDIT: Setting the containing divs' `height` and `width` to `rem` sizes instead of `em` seems to have eliminated this problem. I don't know why. I tried replicating the code in CodePen to see if I could isolate it but it doesn't happen there, so I'm just hoping that someone has seen something like this before and can give me an idea of why this may be happening.

I have a block of images that renders sort of like a table, only it's not. It's just a bunch of inline divs containing `img` tags, and I allow the divs to collapse according to their default behavior when the page resizes, because it works fine, just as long as I set a `min-width` to make sure they remain at least two columns wide.

My problem is that some of the images sometimes load as larger than they should - even though the containing divs have explicit `height` and `width` set (the images are set to `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`). This happens only in Chrome mobile (at least of Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE on PC and Chrome and Firefox mobile), and yet sometimes it works - you can keep refreshing and see issues with different images, and sometimes they're all fine. Firefox mobile renders it fine every time.

So of course I plugged my phone into my PC to load up Remote Devices in Chrome devtools and try to investigate - but as soon as I connect to the Remote Device in devtools, the pictures on the phone instantly resize into their correct positions right before my eyes. Does anybody know why this might happen or what I can do to get them to look right on every load?

Comment: Do you have a plunker or codepen you can share with this happening?

Comment: This is what I would initially look into : https://varvy.com/mobile/content-size-viewport.html

Comment: @nebulr Interestingly, setting the containing divs' sizing to `rem` units seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @nebulr It is required for the code to be posted here, within the question, not a third party site: [mcve] This question may soon be closed for that reason.

Comment: @Rob Why would you close my question? I haven't posted any code to a third party site.

Comment: Did you not read the link I provided you? He wanted you to post your code to a third-party site, that will only get your question closed faster. Again: [mcve] **within your question**.

Comment: @Rob You are being incredibly hostile towards me for no reason. I didn't post my code to a third party site. You said "this question may soon be closed" even though I had not posted to a third party site. What is your problem?

Comment: I didn't say you posted it to a third party site. In fact, I specifically addressed nebulr in my comment, not you. The problem is you are in direct violation of Stack Overflow policy which I have posted for you twice to read with emphasis.

Comment: Your complaint is with Stack Overflow and its staff. Bring it up on meta as to why you don't want to follow the rules and post your markup here. Let us know how well that goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the bootstrap class; `class='img-responsive'`

see example below:

```
<img src="images/footballkids.jpg" class= 'img-responsive' id="img1" onmousemove="cssmouse();">
```

Comment: How can I accomplish this without Bootstrap? I haven't been using Bootstrap and don't really want to bring in a framework just for this one issue.